# Laravel is sending GET instead of POST request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel and POST request. My route is defined as POST and method used in AJAX is POST but it keeps sending GET requests. If I change route to undefined route then it sends POST, but if I aim to this route defined as POST it sends GET request.

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "{{ url('admin/rentacar/save_availability_for_d') }}",
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success(result){
        //
    }
});
```

Route is defined as:

```
Route::post('save_availability_for_d', [
    'as' => 'save_availability_for_d', 
    'uses' => 'RentacarController@saveCarAdjustment'
]);
```

CSRF token is included in meta tags:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

This is what happens in console when I try to send AJAX request:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://www.carsrental.me/public/me/admin/rentacar/save_availability_for_d".
```

and this is what happens if I append just one random character at the end to aim for route that doesn't exists

```
XHR failed loading: POST "http://www.carsrental.me/public/admin/rentacar/save_availability_for_dd".
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the api routes. Making the url `/api/admin/rentacar/save_availability_for_d`. It's not the solution but it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: That would only be the case if it's defined the api routes @SuperDJ, otherwise it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and also **don't forget to clear the cache**

```
$.ajax({
      url: '{{route('save_availability_for_d')}}',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(form).serialize(),
      success: function (result) {
      }
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, this also gives the same result: GET instead of POST

Answer (score 11):

This might not be a Laravel thing.  I've seen this happen if the server-configuration is a little off.  What was happening was the site was set to be `https`, and the Apache config was set to redirect `http`, port 80, requests over to port 443.  But in the process, it was losing track of the request-method (and the GET arguments).

Not certain this is your exact problem, that's kind of an all-or-nothing thing.  But it might be worth a look.

Comment: Spot on, it was a simple issue of http \ https.

Comment: Thanks @kmuenkel 
A similar thing was happening with me for a while and your comment triggered a thought of checking the `HTTP on the base URL of my REST API client and it fixed it.
Thanks for this answer.

Comment:  saved me & team a bunch of time & effort 

Answer (score 4):

As @Claymore has pointed out in the answer above, it's almost always how your server is configured and how you call the API/route. If server is configured to only allow https(port 443) requests, any http(port 80) POST request will be redirected to https by the server and received as a get request. 
This was my main problem because we had recently installed ssl certificates and didn't change the API call protocol from our mobile app, which resulted in failed/undesired requests.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has been down voted! Probably just saved me a whole nights work, good catch, i was at this for a couple of hours.  Server is posting to www and i have redirects.

Comment: Someone probably didn't look close enough at this answer to see that it's not actually a duplicate of mine, just similar. I didn't know that SSL certs could cause this either. So- just gonna go ahead and offset that downvote now. (I get that potential retribution is a concern, but I still really hate when people don't give an explanation for downvotes, especially for newcomers.)

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting effect that hasn't been described here, yet:

In my case, my URL contained a slash "/" at the end.

Like this:

```
    $.ajax( '/my-function/', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'xxx': '{{ $yyy }}',
            '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('DONE data: %o', data);
        if(data) {
            ...            
        }
    }).fail(function(data){
        ...;
    }).always(function(data){
        ...;
    });
```

The redirect from a POST to a GET was done (by jquery, btw), and I was puzzled.

Removing the slash at the end of the URL fixed it.

I.e. like this:

```
    $.ajax( '/my-function', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'xxx': '{{ $yyy }}',
            '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('DONE data: %o', data);
        if(data) {
            ...            
        }
    }).fail(function(data){
        ...;
    }).always(function(data){
        ...;
    });
```

Comment: Same thing happened to me! Thanks!